# I/flutter ( 805): PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null, null)

Tags: flutter

I'm beginner for the flutter, and I'm used   `local_auth: ^1.1.6` for my app fingerprint authentication . when I touch finger print icon but I got a flowing error.

> I/flutter (  805): PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth
> plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null, null)

my flutter  version 2.2.1 / Dart Version .13.1

any one know some solution?

Thanks

here the my code

```
 final LocalAuthentication _localAuthentication = LocalAuthentication();
  String _message = "Not Authorized";

  Future<bool> checkingForBioMetrics() async {
    bool canCheckBiometrics = await _localAuthentication.canCheckBiometrics;
    print(canCheckBiometrics);return canCheckBiometrics;
  }
  Future<void> _authenticateMe() async {
    // 8. this method opens a dialog for fingerprint authentication.
    //    we do not need to create a dialog nut it popsup from device natively.
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      authenticated = await
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: "Authenticate for Testing",
        // message for dialog
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        // show error in dialog
        stickyAuth: true,
      );
      setState(() {_message = authenticated ? "Authorized" : "Not Authorized";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }if (!mounted) return;

  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    checkingForBioMetrics();
    super.initState();
  }

  TextEditingController _phoneController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  bool isSeen = true;
  bool isSignIn = false;
  check (BuildContext context){
    if(_phoneController.text.length > 10 && passwordController.text.length > 5){
      setState(() {
        isSignIn = true;
      });
    }else{
      isSignIn = false;
    }
  }





  Container(
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                _authenticateMe();
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0,),
                                child: Image.asset("assets/icons/ic_finger_print.png",scale:7.1,),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to do is to add the permission (you probably already did this):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.[your.package]">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
  <application...
    ...
    ...
    ...
<manifest>
```

Then you need to change `FlutterActivity` to `FlutterFragmentActivity`:

```
package com.[your.package]

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

If you happen to have Theme.AppCompat issues or if you receive this error:

```
Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(error, You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity., null))
```

Then you need to do this:

Go to `android>app>src>main>res>values>style.xml`.
Change this:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

to

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```